# Same Button Size for Mobile & Desktop

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, responsive

so I have a button with a set height of 45px when I'm previewing on my desktop and scale my window down to what would be considered mobile the button stays 45px. However when I view the website on my actual phone the button is not 45px. I'm testing on the iPhone 6s. Any ideas as to why when you're on an actual phone it would ignore the specific height?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the famous responsive meta tag viewport `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Yeah I do have that in my head tag. Is that what is causing it?

Comment: No, missing that would have been a potential cause. I'm afraid we need to see the code to see what could be the issue. Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example for us to help you https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Here is a link with the basic setup for my button. I'm not sure if you can really view this on your phone and reproduce what I'm seeing though. When I size my window down on my desktop it's fine but on my actual phone it's not the 45px in height. https://jsfiddle.net/Lfp4ykrr/2/